# Getting 5 minute EMA closing value from previous day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm looking to get the previous day's closing value of the 5-minute EMA.  I know how to get the previous day's candle values, that is easy, but when it comes to a specific EMA value on a specific timeframe, that is where I am having trouble.   Example:  5EMA closing value from the previous day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_ema = ema(close, 5)

EMA_MTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", my_ema[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```